# Node.js connectListener still called on socket error

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm having a weird issue with a TCP client - I use `socket.connect()` to connect to the server instance. However, since the server is not running, I receive an error of `ECONNREFUSED` (so far so good).

I handle it using `on('error')` and set a timeout to try and reconnect in 10 seconds. This should continue to fail as long as the server is down. which is the case.

However, as soon as the server is running, it looks like all of the previous sockets are still active, so now I have several client sockets connected to the server.

I tried to call the `destroy` at the beginning of the `on('error')` handler function.

Any ideas how to deal with that?

Thanks!

EDIT: **Code snippet:**

```
var mySocket;
var self = this;
...

var onError = function (error) {
    mySocket.destroy(); // this does not change anything...

    console.log(error);

    // Wait 10 seconds and try to reconnect
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("reconnecting...");
        self.once('InitDone', function () {
            // do something
            console.log("init is done")
        });
        self.init();

    }, 10000);
}
```

Inside *init* function:

```
...
console.log("trying to connect");
mySocket = tls.connect(options, function () {
    console.log("connected!");
    self.emit('InitDone');
});
mySocket.setEncoding('utf8');
mySocket.on('error', onError);
...
```

The result of this is something like the following:

`trying to connect
ECONNREFUSED
reconnecting...
trying to connect
ECONNREFUSED
reconnecting...
trying to connect
ECONNREFUSED
reconnecting...
--> Starting the server here
trying to connect
connected
init is done
connected
init is done
connected
init is done
connected
init is done`

However I would expect only one connection since the previous sockets failed to connect. Hope this clarifies the question.
Thanks!

Comment: Show your code.  It sounds like you're re-attaching handlers over and over again.

Comment: Added code snippet to better illustrate the question. Thanks for the help!