# net.connect: reconnecting tcp net.connects yields connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js

Ive a tcp server client connection that I am trying out

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

everything works the first time client is connected to port and host of server.
next time it gives this error.
why and how can i reconnect/fix this?

conceptually, inner logic aside, this is the server code:

```
net.createServer( function serverConnection (connection) {

            connection.write('whatver i wana write');

            connection.write("\n");

            connection.on('end', function connectionEnd () {
               console.log("Client Connection Ended");
               connection.unref();
               connection.destroy();
               server.close();
           });


       connection.on('close', function connectionClose() {
          console.log("Connection Closed");
          connection.unref();
          connection.destroy();
          server.close();
       });

       connection.on('error', function connectionErr (err) {
           console.error(err);
           server.close();
       });

    });
```

Comment: The server is refusing the connection. The problem is not client-side. Perhaps the server is limiting the number of connections by IP or something, who knows.

Comment: @mscdex added the skeletal code . could see the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the server after the first connection is closed. When you call `server.close()`, the server stops listening for new connections.

Comment: are you familiar with this client side error?: Error: This socket has been ended by the other party] code: 'EPIPE'