# ECONNREFUSED error on stream is not handled by error event and try catch

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, exception

I am using npm request module to forward an incoming request to another server as:

```
app.get("/somepath", function(req, res) {
    var url = proxySetting.global.url + req.url;
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

Here: proxySetting.global.url == http://localhost:4000

Now when i forward incoming request like this to target server, if the target server(localhost:4000) is down or the request is hanged on target server.

There will be an error like ECONNREFUSED or hangup error.

Tried catching these error using domain module like below

```
var d = domain.create();
d.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("Error occoured while forwarding request");
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Error occoured while forwarding request");
});
d.run(function() {
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

Tried to catch error event in several combination

```
    var request = require("request");

module.exports = function(proxySetting) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var url = proxySetting.global.url + req.url;
        url = url.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1") // replacing multiple slashes with one
        console.log("Forwarding request to: " + url);

        function errorHandler(err) {
            console.log("Error occoured while forwarding request");
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send("Error occoured while forwarding request");
        }
        req.on("error", errorHandler);
        res.on("error", errorHandler);
        req.pipe(request(url).on("error",errorHandler)).pipe(res);
    };
};
```

but still the exception is thrown to the process and server crashed
One way i am doing now is

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log("Some unhandled error occoured");
  console.log(err);
  console.log("Stopping server");
  process.exit(1);
});
```

But i think catch uncaughtException and handle is not a proper solution

Comment: I don't have idea about nodeJS error handling but please look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846475/node-js-handling-tcp-socket-error-econnrefused. Is this you are looking for?

Comment: it is the partial solution to the problem, as per the solution they asked to check the connection and then forward request to the remote server. but there is another case when the remote server is up but the request get hang on the remote server and we will get a hang-up error that will kill the proxy server process.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you are not acting on response object in `"errorHandler"`, if you see your code block (given below), `res` is out of scope.

```
function errorHandler(err) {
    console.log("Error occoured while forwarding request");
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Error occoured while forwarding request"); 
} 
req.on("error", errorHandler); 
res.on("error", errorHandler); 
req.pipe(request(url).on("error", errorHandler)) .pipe(res);
```

But, if you act on response object in error handle, there will not be any `uncaughtException`.

I have created a solution, if proxy server is down, it will act on response object on error handle, thus it will not hit `uncaughtException` event.

Here is the solution.

```
var response ;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var url = "http://localhost:3001" + req.url;
    response = res; // I am setting res to global variable here
    req.pipe(request(url).on("error",errorHandler)).pipe(res);

});


function errorHandler(err) {
    response.status(500).send("Error occoured while forwarding request");
}

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log("Some unhandled error occoured");
  console.log(err);
  console.log("Stopping server");
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Here `uncaughtException` event won't be invoked, I have checked in solution to a repo, you can give it a try. Repo location - [here](https://bitbucket.org/arindamnayak_tal/node-http-example) .

Use "Run1.sh" for successful case, "Run2.sh" for proxy server down case.

Comment: Hello Arvind, the problem is not related to res is out of scope, the actual code is updated in question

Comment: I tried the same updated code and it is working now, not sure how, I updated the request package may be due to that need to investigate.

Comment: @MayankKansal can you update me with your request package version, so that I try to reproduce the same.

Comment: 2.75.0 is the current version of request package, not sure about the previous version.

Comment: @MayankKansal, ok, no issues.