# Why doesn't Node.js throw an error when it can't connect to socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-server

When i call both of these functions only the upper one fails and returns an error

```
const { Socket } = require("net")

class Client {
  connect () {
    this.a = new Socket()  
    this.a.connect(this.port, this.host)
    
    this.socket = new Socket()  
    this.socket.connect(this.port, this.host)
  }
}
```

The problem is, that i know that the port this should connect to, is not used. Both functions should throw an error.
If i call the lower one first, still the one with this.a fails.

If i use this.socket for both, the first one always fails even if i change the order of them.

To differentiate between them i used a different port to connect to but also unused.

```
this.socket = new Socket()
this.socket.connect(6743, this.host)

this.a = new Socket()
this.a.connect(6744, this.host)
```

The this.port and this.host variables are not the problem, because if run the script while the server on the port is online it works.

Error Message that should be thrown:

````
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6744
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1145:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6744
}```
````

Comment: I don't understand. Both of them are connecting to the same host and port.

Comment: When the first one throws an error, the second one is never executed.

Comment: That why i said, that i change the order and the one with this.socket gets executed first then the one with socket.a, which is now below, still fails and not the first one.

Comment: You wrote "the first one always fails".

Comment: I meant if i rename this.a to this.socket then the one that is first always fails. With first i don't mean the one which is now first but the one that is first when i rearrange them

Comment: `socket.connect)(` is asynchronous

Comment: It doesn't throw an error, it triggers an `error` event.

Comment: How are you detecting which one is getting the error?

Comment: But then why does the first one throw an error?

Comment: I changed the port number since it is shown in the error message, but i definitely know that the one i changed it to isn't used either

Comment: @Mola1.9 **Which** error does it throw? Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Where do you change the port number?

Comment: @Barmar   ```this.socket = new Socket()
this.socket.connect(6743, this.host)  
this.a = new Socket()  
this.a.connect(6744, this.host)```   Both port numbers are unused, still only the lower one throws an error

Comment: @Bergi events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6744
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1145:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6744
}

Comment: I edited the Post so it is more readable

Answer (score 0):

Like other users have mentioned, the second error is not being triggered because the application effectively stops running after the first error. To prove this, you could try putting a `console.log` between your two attempts to connect to a socket and see that won't run as expected either.

Comment: Sorry, i explained it badly. The problem is if reverse it (as in the second code example i added) still the one with this.a trows an error, besides this.socket being called before it

Comment: So are you saying if you put the one with `this.socket` first, it doesn't throw an error?

Comment: it throws one, but only at this.a, if only run this.socket it doesn't throw an error

Comment: If you are saying running `this.socket` on it's own works, but using `this.a` anywhere doesn't work, without knowing more about your setup, I would be inclined to think there's some tomfoolery happening with variable name collisions. Have you tried changing `this.a` to something like `this.abraKadabra` or something?

Answer (score 0):

In nodeJs some module throw error in event

Socket throw error in `event.on('error')` and you should checked event

I hope below link help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25847067/6759368